# Telerik-Verified-Plugins ImagePicker Plugin Install Failure

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to install ImagePicker plugin in my Ionic app an its throwing the following error.
[image: Error]

Here is my platform info.

[image: Ionic Platform]

Comment: https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/ImagePicker/issues/55 check this issue

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text, rather use the [formatting options](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to make it readable.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the help. It worked. I will remember not to post images. Thanks a lot.